# A question about arguments to a LaTeX macro

Tags: macros, arguments

Several weeks ago, I asked a question about a LaTeX macro to insert an image in a document using an IF statement.  The solution worked perfectly.  Now I have a similar issue.  I have the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\notebook}[1]{
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{\nb#1.png}}
    \end{center}
}
```

where

```
\newcommand{\nb}{"Text Analytics Using Python_Page_"}
```

is the the image to be inserted in the document.  I use this in the document as, for example:

```
\notebook{"01"}
\notebook{"12"}
```

I want to modify this so that to be:

```
\notebook{1, This is an example notebook.} 
\notebook{12, You can see from this notebook that XXX.}
```

Basically, I want to omit the double quotes around the image number (the `"01"` and `"12"`) and I want to add some text below the image in the document.  For the latter, I tried adding a second argument in the macro definition, but it didn't work.  Any help with is is appreciated.

Walt Paczkowski

I'm using LaTeX on a Windows 10 laptop.

```
\newcommand{\notebook}[1]{
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{\nb#1.png}}
    \end{center}
}
```

use a simpler call:

```
\notebook{1, This is some text.}
\notebook{12} Somme example text.}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows which packages you use?

Comment: In general you would save yourself from many problems if you would not use special characters like spaces or underscores in image names.

Comment: Why are you adding the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

- the usual tex method to pass multiple arguments to a macro is `\macroname{arg1}{arg2}` rather than a comma separated list.
- the `""` around `01` should not be necessary because the problematic characters (spaces and _) are in the part of the filename, which is stored in `\nb`. It should be enough to enclose this part in quotation marks. Of course the much better approach would be not use such characters in filenames...

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\notebook}[2]{%
    \newpage%
    \begin{center}%
        \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{\nb#1.png}}%

        #2
    \end{center}%
}

\newcommand{\nb}{"test test_"}

\begin{document}

\notebook{01}{This is an example notebook.}
\notebook{12}{You can see from this notebook that XXX.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks for the help.  Walt